# Error : API response not well-formed (json error code: 4

Tags: curl

I am getting a "API response not well-formed (json error code: 4" error when working on this site and hoping to get some help.
I am using curl API integration for vcommission rest API.
Here is my sample code

```
define('HASOFFERS_API_URL', 'https://tools.vcommission.com/api/coupons.php?apikey='.$key);
$args = array(
     'NetworkId' => 'vcm',
     'Target' => 'Offer',
     'Method' => 'findAll',
     'apikey' => $key
    );
$curlHandle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, HASOFFERS_API_URL . '?' . http_build_query($args));
```

Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Though this is the old thread, I want to answer this question for reference.
In the code, you are fetching coupons from the vCommission API but passing the URL in [vCommission hasOffer's affiliate API](https://developers.tune.com/affiliate/) which is wrong. Both are different.

To access Coupons from vCommission API you can use a simple CURL call. Below is an example of PHP CURL API call:

```
$url = "https://tools.vcommission.com/api/coupons.php?apikey=YOUR_API_KEY";

$response = file_get_contents_curl($url); 
echo $response;

function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');  // This is mandatory. //mandatory field
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $data;
}
```